# How to enable support ticket notification in Chrome Web Store

Tags: notifications, google-chrome-extensions, chrome-web-store

I have an extension listed in the Chrome Web Store. Apparently someone logged a support ticket in July for an error they were getting when trying to run the extension, and I only happened to see it today (over a month later) by chance.

I never received a notification, either by email or through Google+ notifications.  **Is there a setting for enabling notifications for Chrome Web Store support tickets?**

I checked my Google Developer account; all notification/communication settings are enabled:

[image]

I've looked through the [Chrome Web Store help pages](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/?hl=en#topic=6245459) to no avail, and have checked all of my Google notification settings.  Almost all of them are enabled, and the few that aren't are completely unrelated.  I do receive other Google notifications -- recommended posts, AdSense payments, received emails, etc.